# Replace parts of content with regex

Tags: sql-server, regex

We are having HTML content in a table (Azure SQL Server) which contains some URLs to images.

Sample:

```html
<div class="container">
    <hr />
    <div class="head-section" style="max-width: 768px;">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="text-center margin-t-20">
                <h2>Honest feedback can be hard to take. <br class="rwd-break">Gathering it in the first place? Even harder.</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="margin-t-50 text-center">
        <img class="img-fluid" id="platformdiscussion-desktop" style="display: none;" alt="LocalReview global requirements" src="#{cdnUrl}#/cdnFiles/images/landing-pages/Local_Review_WorldMap_en.svg" />
        <img class="img-fluid" id="platformdiscussion-mobile" alt="LocalReview global requirements" src="#{cdnUrl}#/cdnFiles/images/landing-pages/Local_Review_WorldMap_en_mobile.png" />
    </div>
</div>
```

As we move all images to an Azure Blob Storage, case sensitivity matters. Therefore we decided to change all paths to lowercase (in the storage and the URLs).

How can we update all table rows and only change the URLs to lowercase?

Findings of my researches so far:

- A user defined function with CLR (C#) to use regex doesn't work with Azure SQL Server

Comment: No, don't do this, for two reasons.  First, SQL Server has no native support for regex.  Second, you shouldn't be parsing HTML content with regex in the first place.  You should handle this using something like Java or JS which has an HTML DOM parser.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: Thanks for your advice, will consider that.

Answer (score -1):

```
declare @a nvarchar(max) ='<div class="container">
    <hr />
    <div class="head-section" style="max-width: 768px;">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="text-center margin-t-20">
                <h2>Honest feedback can be hard to take. <br class="rwd-break">Gathering it in the first place? Even harder.</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="margin-t-50 text-center">
        <img class="img-fluid" id="platformdiscussion-desktop" style="display: none;" alt="LocalReview global requirements" src="#{cdnUrl}#/cdnFiles/images/landing-pages/Local_Review_WorldMap_en.svg" />
        <img class="img-fluid" id="platformdiscussion-mobile" alt="LocalReview global requirements" src="#{cdnUrl}#/cdnFiles/images/landing-pages/Local_Review_WorldMap_en_mobile.png" />sss
    </div>
    aaaaaaaaa
     <img class="img-fluid" id="platformdiscussion-mobile" alt="LocalReview global requirements" src="#{cdnUrl}#/cdnFiles/images/landing-pages/Local_Review_WorldMap_en_mobile.png" />
   bbbbbbbbbbb
</div>
 <img class="img-fluid" id="platformdiscussion-mobile" alt="LocalReview global requirements" src="#{cdnUrl}#/cdnFiles/images/landing-pages/Local_Review_WorldMap_en_mobile.png" >
   cccccccc
 <img x="123" y="456" >
';


select @a = replace(@a, value, newvalue)
from
(
select value, replace(value, src, lower(src)) as newvalue
from
(
select value, try_cast(concat('<', replace(replace(substring(value, 1, charindex('>', value)), '/>', '>'), '>', '/>')) as xml).value('(img/@src)[1]', 'varchar(max)') as src
from string_split(@a, '<')
where value like 'img%'
) as t
) as xyz
where newvalue is not null;

select @a;
```